# Cocoapods can't resolve dependencies for development pod

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

After update from Xcode 10 to Xcode 10.2 I can't build my project (swift version = 4.2) with the development pod. This development pod contains follow dependencies:

- 'Kingfisher', '5.3.1'
- 'NVActivityIndicatorView'

Build fails on import Kingfisher in the development pod's code. I tried clean the project, reintegrate pods but still get an error. I can provide more information, which help you to find the root cause of this issue.

I get follow error in the development pod's module map:

```
module ###.Swift {
    header "###-Swift.h"  >>> Header '###-Swift.h' not found
    requires objc
}
```

In the build log of the development pod:

```
/path-to-tile/file.swift:11:8: error: no such module 'Kingfisher'
import Kingfisher
```

Comment: Provide us with more information of what kind of error do you experience.

Comment: Proper error screenshot will be helpfull. By the way you can try two more things. 1. go to terminal with your project folder and run  "pod repo update" and if that doesnt solve, try changing deployment target of your project and all your frameworks under pod to same (ex: 10.0)

Answer (score 2):

Switching to Xcode 10.2 does not require you to migrate your base code to Swift 5. And migrating your base code to Swift 5 does not require your pods to migrate to Swift 5 too. Just saying. That version of Kingfisher `5.3.1` targets Swift 5. But no biggie.

When something trivial happens to your project like that, try the following, it helps.

1. pod deintegrate.
2. pod install
3. pod update.
4. Clean project (CMD + SHIFT + K).
5. Clean build (CMD + SHIFT + ALT/OPTION + K).
6. Make sure you're opening the `.xcworkspace` file.
7. Restart Xcode.

As far as I know, when I was using the Xcode 10.2 for the first time and when I was migrating to Swift 5, I experienced similar new errors, but all things were resolved in no time.